# How to modify stored procedure to give null instead of 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to modify a stored procedure to return null instead of 0 ?

Modification request to a stored procedure used for a report. Asked to display blank in the report. Meaning need to return null instead of 0 (zero).

Current code:

```
Approach = ISNULL(Approach, 0) ,
```

Possible new code:

```
Approach = ISNULL(Approach, '') ,
```

Comment: If you were asked to display blank in the report, you might want to clarify whether you want to return blank values or only display values greater than 0. Blank != NULL

Comment: For a report, you should probably return an empty string like in your second example.  Null's return null when you attempt to concatenate to a string for example and may cause other problems to your report.  As @Phoenix notes, its best to know what it is you really want.

Comment: They don't want to see the zeros (0) on the report. which is a tablix made in SSDT.

Comment: I would use the field as it is. The presentation layer can show NULL values the way you want.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out in SSDT.     =IIF(Fields!ColumnName.value=0,"",Sum(Fields!ColumnName.value))

Comment: It should be `SET Approach = NULLIF(Approach, 0)`

Comment: I lost all my "reputation" by posting this question. Here I am thinking I was building something, then bullies come and raid my town.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you sql code add this line

```
CASE WHEN Approach = 0 THEN NULL END AS Approach
```

so in your stored procedure when `Approach` will come as 0 then it will be replaced with `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Went about it in SSDT/SSRS

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!"Field".value)=0,"",Sum(Fields!"Field".value))
```